# Why does my value change when it goes into the for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

```
    int findPair( const int col1, const Item value1, const int col2, const Item value2 ) {
        std::cout << value1 << std::endl; //displays '1'
        for( int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>( this->rows.size() ); i++ ) {
            std::cout << value1 << std::cout; //Changes into '10x5c09c8'
            if( this->rows[ i ]( col1 ) == value1 ) {
                if( this->rows[ i ]( col2 ) == value2 ) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            if( this->rows[ i ]( col1 ) == value2 ) {
                if( this->rows[ i ]( col2 ) == value1 ) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

The Item class is basically a custom container with a union inside of it. All the usual suspect of operators (`=`,`<`,`>`,...) have been overloaded and a copy-contructor created for it. All of that works and has been through a battery of unit tests.

When this is run the first `std::out` prints '1' as expected (the Item holds an int) but then once it goes into the for loop that very same value displays something that looks like a memory address.
Is there some sort of compiler bug here or  am I missing something really obvious?

I've tried without `const`, using `unsigned int` instead of the static cast, copying out the value1 into a new `Item` and then checking it but to no avail.

Here's the `<<` stream operator of the `Item`:

```
        friend std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream &output, const Item item ) {
        switch( item.itsType ) {
            case dataType::NONE:
                output << "NULL";
                break;
            case dataType::INTEGER:
                output << item.item_INT;
                break;
            case dataType::DOUBLE:
                output << item.item_DOUBLE;
                break;
            case dataType::STRING:
                output << item.item_STRING;
                break;
            case dataType::BOOLEAN:
                output << item.item_BOOL;
                break;
            default:
                output << "ERROR!";
                break;
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::cout << value1 << std::cout; //Changes into '10x5c09c8'`

It prints `1` and then address of the object `std::cout`. You likely wanted `std::endl` at the end.

Comment: After staring at the screen for the entire day I did not see that! Muchos thanks! That sorted it out.